# How to create a String Array program that looks for the last match?

Tags: java, arrays, string, match

I'm trying to create a string array program that looks for the last match. For example, when asked for the last word of length 3, the code should locate “was” at index 7. This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to make sure the code returns the position of the last match:

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    String[] words = { "Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb",
                     "it's", "fleece", "was", "white", "as",
                     "snow" };

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Word length: ");
  int wordLength = in.nextInt();

  boolean found = false;
  int pos = 0; 
  while (!found)
  {
     if (wordLength == words[pos].length())
     {
        pos++;
     }
     else
     {
        found = true;
     }
  }

  if (pos > 0)
  {
     System.out.println("Found " + words[pos] + " at position " + pos);
  }
  else
  {
     System.out.println("No word of length " + wordLength);
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use reverse loop

Comment: Try debugging this one yourself.  For example: at the beginning of your `while (!found)` loop, use `System.out.println()` to print the word you're checking.  Now you can find out if you're checking the word `"was"`.  If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String[] words = { "Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb",
                     "it's", "fleece", "was", "white", "as",
                     "snow" };

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Word length: ");
  int wordLength = in.nextInt();

  boolean found = false;
  int pos;
  for(int i = words.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
  {
     if (wordLength == words[i].length())
     {
        pos =i;
        found = true;
        break;
     }
  }

  if (found)
  {
     System.out.println("Found " + words[pos] + " at position " + pos);
  }
  else
  {
     System.out.println("No word of length " + wordLength);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i=(words.length)-1;i>=0;i--){
  if(words[i].length()==3){
     System.out.println("Position:"+i);
     break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that after the length of the first word is not the one you are looking for your `if` statement is evaluated as `false` then you set `found = true` and the `while` loop ends. as @Shubham Agrawa pointed out you could use a reverse loop. Also exchange the contents of the `if` statements and set `pos--` insted of `pos++`. You will also need to check that `pos` is greater or equal to `0` so it doesn't go out of bounds

```
int pos = words.length - 1; 
      while (!found && pos >= 0)
      {
         if (wordLength == words[pos].length())
         {
             found = true;
         }
         else
         {
            pos--;
         }
      }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'll prefer using for loop instead of while. start from last index and break when you found a match and print that index number.

```
for(int i=words.length-1;i>-1;i--) {
            if (wordLength == words[i].length()) {
                pos=i;
                found = true;
                break;
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I guess this the most efficient and shortest method to get what you
>   requires.
>
> **It takes an int as an input parameter and then search from last to
>   first for the element with size equal to input lenght.**

**Code:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] words = { "Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb",
                "it's", "fleece", "was", "white", "as",
                "snow" };

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Word length: ");
        int wordLength = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("word lenght ="+wordLength);
        int size=words.length;
        System.out.println("Lenght of array ="+size);

        for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--){
            if(words[i].length()==wordLength){
                System.out.println(words[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:-**

```
Word length: 5
word lenght =5
Lenght of array =11
white
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 has a good way to do this with `Stream`s. After collecting the word length (assume it is stored in the variable `wordLength`, and that the array is called `words`):

```
Optional<String> lastMatchingWord = Arrays.stream(words).filter(word -> word.length() == wordLength).reduce((a, b) -> b);
if (lastMatchingWord.isPresent())
{
    String word = lastMatchingWord.get();
    int index = Arrays.asList(words).lastIndexOf(word);
    //Use these values as you wish.
}
else
{
    //Handle no match found procedure however you want.
}
```

The first bit makes a `Stream` from the array (`Arrays.stream`), and then filters it down to only the elements with the desired length (the name `filter` is self-explanatory, the actual procedure uses a Java 8 lambda to check for equality, and only values for `word` which cause this function to return `true` are left in the `Stream`), then gets the last element (`reduce` is designed to reduce a `Stream` of element down to a single instance of that element type. It is frequently used to fold all elements into a single element (think adding together a bunch of `Integer`s, for example). In this case, we're simply plucking out the last value, because our accumulator always discards the accumulated value and sets the new value to whatever the next element is).

The `reduce` operation returns an `Optional`, which will be empty if the result of the `filter` operation returned an empty `Stream` (read: the `Optional` will be empty if no words are the desired length). Thus, if `lastMatchingWord.isPresent()`, you can grab the word out of the `Optional` as a `String`, an find its index in the original array. If it isn't there, you can deal with that as appropriate. Overall, you end up with less code than manual loops.